Problemas de longitud en constructor de java
Tengo un formulario para insertar datos, pero tengo problemas de tamaño en el constructor, porque solo acepta 9 parametros, pero yo necesito 10, el problema esta en que en la clase constructora si estan definidos los 10 parametros, pero en la clase donde se insertan los datos sigue sin aceptar 10 parametros.
Este es mi clase constructora:
public class Prescripcion_medicamento {
    
    private int id_pres_medica;
    private int id_prescripcion;
    private int id_medicamento;
    private String dosis;
    private String intervalo;
    private int num_dias;
    private Timestamp fecha_inicio;
    private Timestamp hora_inicio;
     private int num_unidades;
    private int id_paciente;

    
    public  Prescripcion_medicamento(int id_pres_medica, int id_prescripcion, int id_medicamento, String dosis, String intervalo, int num_dias, Timestamp fecha_inicio, Timestamp hora_inicio, int id_paciente) {
    this.id_pres_medica = id_pres_medica;
    this.id_prescripcion = id_prescripcion;
    this.id_medicamento = id_medicamento;
    this.dosis = dosis;
    this.intervalo = intervalo;
    this.num_dias = num_dias;
    this.fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio;
    this.hora_inicio = hora_inicio;
     this.num_unidades = num_unidades;
    this.id_paciente = id_paciente;
    }
    
    public Prescripcion_medicamento() {
        this.id_pres_medica = 0;
        this.id_prescripcion = 0;
        this.id_medicamento = 0;
        this.dosis = null;
        this.intervalo = null;
        this.num_dias = 0;
        this.fecha_inicio = null;
        this.hora_inicio = null;
        this.num_unidades = 0;
         this.id_paciente = 0;
    }

    public int getId_pres_medica() {
        return id_pres_medica;
    }

    public void setId_pres_medica(int id_pres_medica) {
        this.id_pres_medica = id_pres_medica;
    }

    public int getId_prescripcion() {
        return id_prescripcion;
    }

    public void setId_prescripcion(int id_preiscripcion) {
        this.id_prescripcion = id_prescripcion;
    }

    public int getId_medicamento() {
        return id_medicamento;
    }

    public void setId_medicamento(int id_medicamento) {
        this.id_medicamento = id_medicamento;
    }

    public String getDosis() {
        return dosis;
    }

    public void setDosis(String docis) {
        this.dosis = dosis;
    }

    public String getIntervalo() {
        return intervalo;
    }

    public void setIntervalo(String interbalo) {
        this.intervalo = intervalo;
    }
    
     public int getNum_dias() {
        return num_dias;
    }

    public void setNum_dias(int num_dias) {
        this.num_dias = num_dias;
    }


    public Timestamp getFecha_inicio() {
        return fecha_inicio;
    }

    public void setFecha_inicio(Timestamp fecha_inicio) {
        this.fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio;
    }

    public void setHora_inicio(Timestamp hora_inicio) {
        this.hora_inicio = hora_inicio;
    }
    
      public int getNum_unidades() {
        return num_unidades;
    }

    public void setNum_unidades(int num_unidades) {
        this.num_unidades = num_unidades;
    }

    
    
    public int getId_paciente() {
        return id_paciente;
    }

    public void setId_paciente(int id_paciente) {
        this.id_paciente = id_paciente;
    }
    
    
}

y esta es la clase donde se insertan los datos:
public class Cls_prescripcion_medicamento {
    
    int res = 0;
    private final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO prescripcion_medicamento (id_pres_medica, id_prescripcion, id_medicamento, dosis, intervalo, num_dias, fecha_inicio, hora_inicio, num_unidades, id_paciente)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    private final String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM prescripcion_medicamento";
    private PreparedStatement PS;
    private DefaultTableModel DTM;
    private final Conexion CN;
    private ResultSet RS;
    
    public Cls_prescripcion_medicamento(){
        this. PS = null;
        this. CN = new Conexion();
    }
    
    public int insertarDatos(int id_pres_medica,int id_prescripcion, int id_medicamento, String dosis,  String intervalo, int num_dias, Timestamp fecha_inicio, Timestamp hora_inicio, int num_unidades, int id_paciente){
        int res = 0;
        try{
           PS = CN.getConexion().prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
            PS.setInt(1, id_pres_medica);
            PS.setInt(2, id_prescripcion);
            PS.setInt(3, id_medicamento);
            PS.setString(4, dosis);
            PS.setString(5, intervalo);
            PS.setInt(6, num_dias);
            PS.setTimestamp(7, fecha_inicio);
            PS.setTimestamp(8, hora_inicio);
            PS.setInt(9, num_unidades);
            PS.setInt(10, id_paciente);
            res = PS.executeUpdate();
            if (res>0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro exitoso", "Alta", JOptionPane. INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar datos"+e.getMessage(), "Alta", JOptionPane. INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }finally{
            PS= null;
            CN.close();
        }
        return res;
    }
     public ArrayList<Prescripcion_medicamento> generarLista(){
       ArrayList<Prescripcion_medicamento> lista = new ArrayList();
       //order by idequipo
       String SQL_Venta = "Select * from prescripcion_medicamento";
       try{
           PS = CN.getConexion().prepareStatement(SQL_Venta);
           RS = PS.executeQuery();
           while(RS.next()){
               
               lista.add(new Prescripcion_medicamento (
                    RS.getInt("id_pres_medica"),
                    RS.getInt("id_prescripcion"),
                    RS.getInt("id_medicamento"),
                    RS.getString("dosis"),
                    RS.getString("intervalo"),
                    RS.getInt("num_dias"),
                    RS.getTimestamp("fecha_inicio"),
                    RS.getTimestamp("hora_inicio"),
                    RS.getInt("num_unidades"),
                    RS.getInt("id_paciente")));

           }
           
       }catch(SQLException e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al consultar la BD"+e);
       }finally{
           PS = null;
           RS = null;
           CN.close();
       }
       return lista;
   }
    
}

y este es el error que me da: "no suitable constructor found for Prescripcion_medicamento(int,int,int, String, String, int, Timestamp, Timestamp,int,int)
constructor Prescripcion_medicamento.Prescripcion_medicamento(int, int, int, String, String, int, Timestamp, Timestamp, int) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Prescripcion_medicamento. Prescripcion_medicamento() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)".
No entiendo porque me da este error si estan definidos los 10 parámetros en el constructor, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

El error indica que no hay un constructor en la clase Prescripcion_medicamento que acepte diez parámetros.
En la clase Prescripcion_medicamento en el constructor , debes agregar el parámetro num_unidades, ya que no existe, agregalo antes de id_paciente:
 public  Prescripcion_medicamento(int id_pres_medica, int id_prescripcion, int id_medicamento, String dosis, String intervalo, int num_dias, Timestamp fecha_inicio, Timestamp hora_inicio, int num_unidades, int id_paciente) {
    this.id_pres_medica = id_pres_medica;
    this.id_prescripcion = id_prescripcion;
    this.id_medicamento = id_medicamento;
    this.dosis = dosis;
    this.intervalo = intervalo;
    this.num_dias = num_dias;
    this.fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio;
    this.hora_inicio = hora_inicio;
     this.num_unidades = num_unidades;
    this.id_paciente = id_paciente;
    }

